# Отправка HTTPS запроса из Java-приложения

Tags: java, https

Какие существуют способы для отправки https-запросов из десктопного java-приложения? Особенно интересен пример исходного кода.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Самый примитивный способ — это использовать [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html). Вот пример без обработки ошибок, кодировок и прочей шелухи:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URLConnection connection = new URL("https://www.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectList").openConnection();

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    char[] buffer = new char[256];
    int rc;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while ((rc = reader.read(buffer)) != -1)
        sb.append(buffer, 0, rc);

    reader.close();

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

В случае, если окажется, что стандартный `URLConnection` (точнее, по факту создаётся [`HttpsUrlConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html)) чего-то не может, то используйте [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

Comment: Этот код не отличается от кода отправки http-запроса (кроме самого url, конечно). Поправьте, если ошибаюсь. На просторах интернета пишут, что java.net.URL не поддерживает https, правда статья очень старая, вероятно, уже неактуальна http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip96.html

Comment: Этот код, что я привёл работает. Я не знаю кто там чего пишет...

Comment: Спасибо, моя проблема похоже не из-за секьюрности, а из-за того, что эта страничка откроется только с Cookies.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(inputLine);
        in.close();
        System.out.println(sb); 
    }
}
```

Источник https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) построенный на apache http api.

```
String uri = "https://www.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectList";
HttpRequest<String> httpRequest = HttpRequestBuilder.createGet(uri, String.class)
.responseDeserializer(ResponseDeserializer.ignorableDeserializer()).build();

public void send(){
  ResponseHandler<String> response = httpRequest.execute(someParamsYouWant);
  System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
  System.out.println(response.get()); //retuns response body
}
```