# Как безопасно передать пароль по https?

Tags: java, https

Если я использую http, то всё что я по нему передаю, всё это не шифруется. А что с https? Там шифруются даже url запросы, типа get? Если просто обычным get url запросом передать пароль типа https://bla.com?pass=pass это же не будет безопасно, или будет? Если нет, то как правильно это делать? Например в Java, если посмотреть код из ответа: [Отправка HTTPS запроса из Java-приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4556/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-https-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), то всё, чем отличается https запрос от http, это тем что там в url написано https, а не http. Или я чего-то не замечаю и не понимаю?

Comment: Зачем вообще передавать пароль?

Comment: Ну пароль стоит передавать через **POST** запрос и только при авторизации, а дальше он и не нужен вовсе

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Http от https отличается тем, что https трафик шифруется по протоколам SSL и TLS с помощью специальных сертификатов. Шифруется вся часть запроса(cookie, headers, body), в том числе параметры URL.

Но отправлять секретные данные в URL не рекомендуется. Для этого лучше воспользоваться POST запросом.

Вот цитата, описывающая проблематику:

> URLs are stored in web server logs - typically the whole URL of each
>   request is stored in a server log. This means that any sensitive data
>   in the URL (e.g. a password) is being saved in clear text on the
>   server

Если коротко, то:

URL хранятся в логах веб сервера вместе со всеми параметрами. Это значит, что любые секретные данные будут сохранены в этих самых логах.